# No Gpio input signals with LightningDriver

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to count Gpio input signals with ~30Hz frequency input through the GPIO Interface on a raspberry pi2 using c# on Windows 10 Iot core. I am loosing most of the signals though. So I have activated the Lightning Driver, I included the c++ Lightning interfaces and my LightningProvider seems to initialize correctly. I am testing for LightningProvider.IsLightningEnabled and initializing the GpioController accordingly.
The compiler seems to be happy and generates a executable that I am remote debugging on my Raspberry Pi2

My GPIO output continues to drive the Soft-PWM application that I have programmed. The only problem is that the EventHandler which is set up to count my signals is not getting invoked any more when I activate the LightningDriver on the Pi.
Or to make it short: As soon as I activate the LightningDriver I am not receiving any more input signals.
Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your GPIO initialization could help here, but I had a similar problem where I stopped getting events back from my GPIO pins after the first or second time it was fired.

I had the pins set up in the constructor and they were just local variables with event handlers defined to private methods.

The solution was to give my pins more scope because .NET was disposing of those pin events after they were used once. My code ultimately looked like this:

```
private readonly GpioController _gpio;
private readonly GpioPin _rateOnePin;
private readonly GpioPin _rateTwoPin;
```

with the following constructor code:

```
_gpio = GpioController.GetDefault();

if (_gpio != null)
{
    _rateOnePin = _gpio.OpenPin(5);
    _rateOnePin.ValueChanged += RateOneReceived;

    _rateTwoPin = _gpio.OpenPin(6);
    _rateTwoPin.ValueChanged += RateTwoReceived;
}
```

I'm not sure why it felt the need to dispose of them, but making this did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - but thats not it. I think I got the reason though: There was a comment on MSDN regarding LightningDrivers that the current release doesn't support interrupts yet. So I will convert to polling to see if that works.